# How to get windows 10 device specifications pen and touch properties with python?

Tags: python, windows, operating-system

I would like to get windows 10 device specifications pen and touch properties with python

[image]

I try to use two ways :

1. systeminfo in command line
2. msinfo32

Both ways did not find the answer,Is there any way to get this?

I expect that there can be Python Package or other methods

Answer (score 1):

you can use pyglet module to get all devices connected to your pc/laptop

first install pyglet `pip install pyglet`

code

```py
import pyglet

devices = pyglet.input.get_devices()
print(devices)
```

reference question
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54003194/how-can-i-access-tablet-pen-data-via-python)

[pyglet docs](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/programming_guide/input.html)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but this method can only find the input device